# List of lengths of runs of elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list where a few distinct numbers occur, e.g.

```
{41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41}
```

I want to extract the information of how many times in a row each number occurs. For the above list,

```
{{3,7},{1}}
```

I actually already have something that works, but it seems excessively complicated and amateurish. Any ideas to improve this?

```
(Take[#, All, {2}] // Flatten) & /@
 Sort[
  GatherBy[{#[[1]], Length[#]} & /@ Union@Split@INPUTLIST,
   First],
  First@First[#1] < First@First[#2] &]
```

Comment: So you don't have to know which result corresponds to which value?

Comment: They're supposed to be in increasing order, so here it's runs of 41 first, then runs of 1009. I suppose if they were more general than integers, you might want to include that information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same idea, a bit cleaner:

```
DeleteDuplicates /@ MapAt[Length, GatherBy[Split[yourListHere], First], {All, All}]
```

And a generic function, with option to annotate with element identities:

```
runsList[list_, names_: False] := 
  Module[{gb = GatherBy[Split[list], First], runs},
   runs = DeleteDuplicates /@ MapAt[Length, gb, {All, All}];
   If[names, Transpose[{Flatten[Union @@@ gb], runs}],runs]];

test = {41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41, 41};

runsList[test]
runsList[test, True]

(*

{{3, 7, 4}, {1}}

{{41, {3, 7, 4}}, {1009, {1}}}

*)
```

And a shorter version if you always want annotations:

```
{#[[1, 1]], Length /@ #} & /@ GatherBy[(Tally@Split@#)[[All, 1]], First] &[yourListHere]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41};
```

**[GroupBy](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html?q=GroupBy)**

```
GroupBy[Split @ list, First -> Length, DeleteDuplicates]
```

> <|41 -> {3, 7}, 1009 -> {1}|>

```
Values @ %
```

> {{3, 7}, {1}}

**[SequenceCases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html?q=SequenceCases)**

```
SequenceCases[list, x : {Repeated[a_]} :> Length[x]]
```

> {3, 1, 7, 1, 3}

Answer (score 4):

Using `PositionIndex`, `SequenceCases` and [ConsecutiveQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140472/ordered-subsequences-of-consecutive-integers):

```
list = {41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41};

Length /@ SequenceCases[#, {__}?ConsecutiveQ] & /@ PositionIndex[list]

(*<|41 -> {3, 7, 3}, 1009 -> {1, 1}|>*)
```

Comment: +1, I didn't even know that we have `ConsecutiveQ `

Answer (score 3):

I have supported rasher's answer. I just post this as an example using `Reap` and `Sow`.

```
fun[u_, n_: Identity] := 
 Last@Reap[Sow[Length[#], First@#] & /@ Split[u], _, #1 -> n@#2 &]
```

Using:

```
data = {41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 
   41};
```

If you want to collect all the runs:

```
fun[data]
```

gives:

```
{41 -> {3, 7, 3}, 1009 -> {1, 1}}
```

If you want to just want unique run lengths:

```
fun[data,DeleteDuplicates]
```

gives:

```
{41 -> {3, 7}, 1009 -> {1}}
```

If you want to do something with the runs, e.g. `Mean`:

```
fun[data, Mean]
```

yields:

```
{41 -> 13/3, 1009 -> 1}
```

Its timing is **less** efficient than any of rashers, e.g.

```
{#[[1, 1]], Length /@ #} & /@ 
     GatherBy[(Tally@Split@#)[[All, 1]], First] &[
   RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10000000]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

yields 14.403590 seconds.

versus:

```
fun[RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10000000]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

16.118732 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41};
```

Using `PositionIndex` (new in 10.0)

```
With[{p = PositionIndex @ list},
 Thread[Keys[p] -> (Length /@ Split[#, #2 - #1 == 1 &] & /@ Values[p])]]
```

{41 -> {3, 7, 3}, 1009 -> {1, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

## use `SequenceCases`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
INPUTLIST = {41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 
   41, 41};
SequenceCases[INPUTLIST, x : {Repeated[a_]} :> {a, Length[x]}]
```

```
{{41, 3}, {1009, 1}, {41, 7}, {1009, 1}, {41, 3}}
```

## Use `Split`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
INPUTLIST = {41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 1009, 41, 
   41, 41};

grouped = Split[INPUTLIST];
output = Map[{First[#], Length[#]} &, grouped]
```

```
{{41, 3}, {1009, 1}, {41, 7}, {1009, 1}, {41, 3}}
```