# Ordered Subsequences of consecutive integers

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list

```
  list={3, 4, 8, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}
```

and I want to find all the ordered subsequences of consecutive integers

in my example I should get

> ```
>  {{3, 4}, {1, 2}, {5, 6, 7}}
> ```

as you can see `{5,6}`, `{6,7}` must NOT be included in the final result

Comment: closely related: [**23607**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/5478)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Didn't find an exact duplicate so let's use another closely related:

[How to detect if a sequence of integers is consecutive](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39211/5478), credits to [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods)

```
consecutiveQ = Most[#] == Rest[#] - 1 &

SequenceCases[{3, 4, 8, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}, {_, __}?consecutiveQ]
```

> ```
> {{3, 4}, {1, 2}, {5, 6, 7}}
> ```

Comment: thanx.it works! and it's elegant

Comment: @Jenny Elegant, but unfortunately extremely slow on long lists.  Please see my answer for a comparison.  (My apologies Kuba for "attacking" your method.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard always feel free to do so as almost always I ignore performance in my answers.

Answer (score 10):

```
Select[Split[list, #2 - #1 == 1 &], Length[#] > 1 &]
```

Also can get the same result

Comment: Can you modify this so that if you have a list like {1,2,3,5,7,8,9} you will get back {{1,2,3},{5},{7,8,9}} instead of {{1,2,3},{7,8,9}} ???? I am tempted to post the question but I thought I would ask first.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to do this, you just set Length[#]>=1& ...

Answer (score 3):

Based on `intervals` from [Find subsequences of consecutive integers inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121#23623):

```
consec[a_List] :=
  SparseArray[Differences@a, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"] //
    {a[[Prepend[# + 1, 1]]], a[[Append[#, -1]]]} & //
      Range @@@ Pick[#\[Transpose], Unitize[Subtract @@ #], 1] &

consec[{3, 4, 8, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}]
```

> ```
> {{3, 4}, {1, 2}, {5, 6, 7}}
> ```

Benchmark including the two existing answers as `fnK` and `fnY`:

```
consecutiveQ = Most[#] == Rest[#] - 1 &;

fnK[lst_] := SequenceCases[lst, {_, __}?consecutiveQ]
fnY[lst_] := Select[Split[lst, #2 - #1 == 1 &], Length[#] > 1 &]

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{fnK, fnY, consec}, RandomInteger[9, #] &, 2]
```

[image]

(Note the log-log scale.)